# Troubleshooting linking library in React Native

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native

I wouldn't be posting here if I wasn't having a ton of problems and if I had not spent several days trying to link a library correctly in React Native. Mostly I haven't had issues, but this particular library has seemingly been almost impossible.

https://github.com/jerson/react-native-palette-full

Here's my code, which is very basic:

```
import Palette from "react-native-palette-full";

    componentDidMount() {
Palette.getAllSwatchesFromUrl(this.state.merchant.coverPhoto);
}
```

Exactly what you would expect from the instructions on the library.

Instead I am getting this:

[image: Error message]

I've tried linking it manually:

```
react-native link react-native-palette-full
```

I've tried these manual installation instructions:

```
In XCode, in the project navigator, right click Libraries ➜ Add Files to [your project's name]
Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-palette-full and add RNPalette.xcodeproj
In XCode, in the project navigator, select your project. Add libRNPalette.a to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With Libraries
Go to Podfile and add "SDWebImage", "~>4.3.3"
Run your project (Cmd+R)<
```

This just leads to RNPalette not being found, despite the project being right there under my libraries in Xcode.

How can I troubleshoot this and get it working? I'm quite literally tearing my hair out - all I want to do is get a color swatch from an image, and it seems virtually impossible in React Native.

I am on RN .60

EDIT:

I have been trying linking manually, and I am consistently getting the error, no matter what I try, that ImageLoader can't be found:

```
#import <React/RCTImageLoader.h> 'React/RCTImageLoader.h' file not found
```

I have also tried adding it as a dependency in the podspec file in the library:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "RNPalette"
  s.version      = "1.0.0"
  s.summary      = "RNPalette"
  s.description  = <<-DESC
                 Info about colors from images or url, compatible with **Android** and **iOS**
                   DESC
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/jerson/react-native-palette-full"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  # s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "FILE_LICENSE" }
  s.author             = { "author" => "jeral17@gmail.com" }
  s.platform     = :ios, "7.0"
  s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/jerson/react-native-palette-full.git", :tag => "master" }
  s.source_files  = "RNPalette/**/*.{h,m}"
  s.requires_arc = true


  s.dependency "React"
  s.dependency "SDWebImage", "~>4.3.3"
  s.dependency 'React-Core'
  s.dependency 'React-RCTImage'

end
```

How can I link this library? Is there any way?

EDIT: Upon trying one of the suggestions below, I get the following error messages:

[image: First error]

[image: Second error]

[image: Third error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have completed the manual linking, follow the steps below

**SOLUTION 1:**

1. Open your project in Xcode
2. Right-click on *Libraries* folder and click on *Add Files to 'PROJECT_NAME'*, add the file from this path `node_modules/react-native/React/React.xcodeproj`. I have attached a screenshot for your reference below.

[image]

3. Clean the project and run.

**SOLUTION 2:**

1. Open your project in Xcode
2. Click on the arrow to open Libraries folder and select `RNPalette.xcodeproj`
3. Select `Build Settings`, navigate to `Header Search Path` and add the following line `"$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/Headers"` make sure it is recursive. I have attached a screenshot below

[image]

4. Clean and Build.

It working fine for me now. Below is an example of it.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

import Palette from "react-native-palette-full";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
  Palette.getNamedSwatchesFromUrl('https://kinsta.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/change-wordpress-url-1.png').then((res)=>{
      console.warn("data",res);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
          <ScrollView
            contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
            style={styles.scrollView}>
            <Header />
            <View style={styles.body}>
              <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
                <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                  Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
              </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
                <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                  <ReloadInstructions />
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
                <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                  <DebugInstructions />
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
                <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                  Read the docs to discover what to do next:
              </Text>
              </View>
              <LearnMoreLinks />
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Let me know if you face any issues. If you want I can share the POC with you. I have it working on React-Native 0.60.0.

Comment: Hrm, now I am getting this error - which seems to be only partially related? lSDWebImage is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

Comment: Did you run pod install? in the ios folder?

Comment: Yes. I also received an error about needing support for iOS 13 despite trying to run it on a 12.2 simulator, so I’m also updating Xcode right now to see if that helps

Comment: Also remove,  
s.dependency 'React-Core'
s.dependency 'React-RCTImage'
From the podspec that you added

Comment: I posted my error messages. It seems to have something to do with SD Web Image - but I absolutely have run pod install several times, and it says it is installed and it is listed in the podfile

Comment: Ok, I completely removed react-native-palette-full, and redid everything and it appears to work now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

After manual linking, to fix the `React/RCTImageLoader.h not found` error
go to:

project target, `Linked Framework and Libraries` click `+` and add `libRCTImage.a`

[image]

If any other RCT dependency is missing make sure it added in `Linked Framework and Libraries`.

OR: if you use React in pod file you could add a line in pod file like this:

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'RCTImage' # <- Add this line
  ]
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
```

**NOTE:** Some people reported that `RCTImage` was renamed into `React-RCTImage` for RN 0.60+